# jQuery :contains works in FF, Safari and Chrome and not Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer, jsfiddle

I have setup some code on JSFiddle. The jQuery `:contains` selector works fine in Firefox, Safari and Chrome but not in Internet Explorer 7, 8 or 9.

The working code is located here.

http://jsfiddle.net/2nhUt/18/

I made the XML a variable for display purposes, but when the JSFiddle is opened in IE the Result doesn't show up. I have read a lot where people have the :`contains` selctor working in IE, and I am not sure what the issue is.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

If there is a better way of displaying the latest article in a RSS feed where the title contains "QA" that would be helpful too.

Thank you.

Comment: IE might encode it as `&amp;`. Does that work?

Comment: I updated it to remove the & to avoid any issues there. It is now just QA and still doesnt work.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you be more specific. I don't see a difference between the files except in one the Q&A isn't underlined; both links don't work on either page...

Comment: I have a RSS feed. I want to display the latest article with based on a specific string. In this case I want to display the latest article where the title include "QA". My code gets the XML file and shows the first item with "QA" in the title. The result in FF displays "Article number two : QA with Brandon" and skipped "Article number one : Random Title" because there is no "QA" in the title. This result is visible in Firefox, Safari and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alex mentioned in the comments putting `&` in xml is not valid. Replacing that with `&#038;` in both cases in the string works fine in IE8.

Oh, and in your html there was an extra `</div>` caused by a `<div/></div>` in the middle somewhere.

I also threw in a parseXML since I'm assuming your GET returns the datatype as XML.

[Forked jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahCjR/) that works in IE8.

Here is a XML [validator](http://www.validome.org/xml/) - I just popped that in and it points to the `&` (i thought at first there was nesting issues).

If you can't control the source, you might do a quick regex to fix it (not suggested).

Comment: I am going to need to feed the RSS other than through a var. Right now I have `jQuery.get('news.xml', function(RSSqa){`  How would I run the same jQuery.parseXML when it is within the function(RSSqa)?

Comment: jQuery.get('2011.xml', function parseXML(RSSqa){
jQuery(RSSqa).find("item:contains('Q & A with'):lt(1)").each(function(){

This works in FF, but not in IE. I don't see the difference. Both your example and mine are using the jQuery parseXML function

Comment: I have been digging more and I have realized IE doesnt parse white space very well. The example you gave me works great because there is no white space. When I .get a XML file with whitespace and I use the :contains selector it gets all wonky.